# XPath: how to find nodes with only the specified attributes and no other attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

The following example illustrates my problem:

```
<nodes>
   <node at1="1" at2="2"> 12 </node>
   <node at1="1" at2="2" at3="3"> 123 </node>
   <node at1="1"> 1 </node>        <-----find this node
</nodes>
```

`/nodes/node[@at1]` returns all three nodes, but I am looking for nodes with only the "at1" attribute and no other attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This finds `node` having attribute `@at1`, and no other attributes:

```
//node[@at1 and count(@*) = 1]
```

If you want to permit another optional attribute `x`, you can do like this:

```
//node[@at1 and count(@*) - count(@x) = 1]
```

What if you have nodes with `xmlns` namespace declaration like this:

```
<nodes>
   <node at1="1"> 1 </node>
   <node at1="2" xmlns="http://xyz"> 2 </node>
</nodes>
```

You can match both nodes like this:

```
//*[name()='node' and @at1 and count(@*) = 1]
```

To match only the node with `xmlns`:

```
//*[name()='node' and @at1 and count(@*) = 1 and namespace-uri()='http://xyz']
```

To match only the node without `xmlns`:

```
//*[name()='node' and @at1 and count(@*) = 1 and namespace-uri()='']
```

Comment: This works in many cases, but if - in an html document - I replace at2 by xmlns, then it does not work. Try it on <html><body><div at1="1" xmlns="xyz"> Div1 </div></body></html>. It shouldn't return any node.

Comment: `xmlns` is not an attribute, but a namespace declaration

Comment: Oh! In my code I had DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false). After I changed it to "true", I'm getting only one node in the response. I'll accept this answer in a couple of days unless I get a better one.

Comment: @janos: count(@xmlns) is always zero and xmlns declaration is not counted in count(@*). Your update needs to be corrected.

Comment: @janos: The solution you stated above works because the xmlns declarations are neither counted in count(@*) nor in count(@xmlns). I thnk it is sufficient (in the above case, even with xmlns there) to say //node[@at1 and count(@*)=1].

Comment: @janos: We are not on the same page yet. Your second solution is incorrect because count(@xmlns) is ALWAYS ZERO, whether or not attribute/declaration xmlns is present!! This is true in general, not just in the above example! As markdark pointed out above, xmlns is a declaration, not an attribute.